# Local Notification shows sprocket icon instead of app icon

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm scheduling local notifications in my App. When they show up however, the wrong icon is shown in the banner. I created a clean project with the notification and the app icon and in that project it works. In my big projectfile it doesn't. I'd rather not migrate my complete project to a new xCode project.

has anybody seen this before?

[Screenshot of wrong notification icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWnOZ.png)

Comment: Just guessing that you got a wrong or out of date icon in your plist.

Comment: That is why I checked the icon in a different project. works correct with the same icon and same plist settings.